# Converting Map[String,Any] to a case class using Shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633563/converting-nested-case-classes-to-nested-maps-using-shapeless) asks about mapping a case class to a Map[String,Any]. I was wondering what would be the other way around, converting Map[String,Any] to a case class. Given the following map:

```
val mp = Map("name" -> "Tom", "address" -> Map("street" -> "Jefferson st", "zip" -> 10000))
```

Convert it to a case class of `Person`:

```
case class Person(name:String, address:Address)
case class Address(street:String, zip:Int)

val p = Person("Tom", Address("Jefferson st", 10000))
```

with something like this:

```
val newP = mp.asCC[Person]
assert(newP.get == p)
```

How should I do that with Shapeless.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's an off-the-cuff, mostly untested solution. First for the type class:

```
import shapeless._, labelled.{ FieldType, field }

trait FromMap[L <: HList] {
  def apply(m: Map[String, Any]): Option[L]
}
```

And then the instances:

```
trait LowPriorityFromMap {
  implicit def hconsFromMap1[K <: Symbol, V, T <: HList](implicit
    witness: Witness.Aux[K],
    typeable: Typeable[V],
    fromMapT: Lazy[FromMap[T]]
  ): FromMap[FieldType[K, V] :: T] = new FromMap[FieldType[K, V] :: T] {
    def apply(m: Map[String, Any]): Option[FieldType[K, V] :: T] = for {
      v <- m.get(witness.value.name)
      h <- typeable.cast(v)
      t <- fromMapT.value(m)
    } yield field[K](h) :: t
  }
}

object FromMap extends LowPriorityFromMap {
  implicit val hnilFromMap: FromMap[HNil] = new FromMap[HNil] {
    def apply(m: Map[String, Any]): Option[HNil] = Some(HNil)
  }

  implicit def hconsFromMap0[K <: Symbol, V, R <: HList, T <: HList](implicit
    witness: Witness.Aux[K],
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[V, R],
    fromMapH: FromMap[R],
    fromMapT: FromMap[T]
  ): FromMap[FieldType[K, V] :: T] = new FromMap[FieldType[K, V] :: T] {
    def apply(m: Map[String, Any]): Option[FieldType[K, V] :: T] = for {
      v <- m.get(witness.value.name)
      r <- Typeable[Map[String, Any]].cast(v)
      h <- fromMapH(r)
      t <- fromMapT(m)
    } yield field[K](gen.from(h)) :: t
  }
}
```

And then a helper class for convenience:

```
class ConvertHelper[A] {
  def from[R <: HList](m: Map[String, Any])(implicit
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
    fromMap: FromMap[R]
  ): Option[A] = fromMap(m).map(gen.from(_))
}

def to[A]: ConvertHelper[A] = new ConvertHelper[A]
```

And the example:

```
case class Address(street: String, zip: Int)
case class Person(name: String, address: Address)

val mp = Map(
  "name" -> "Tom",
  "address" -> Map("street" -> "Jefferson st", "zip" -> 10000)
)
```

And finally:

```
scala> to[Person].from(mp)
res0: Option[Person] = Some(Person(Tom,Address(Jefferson st,10000)))
```

This will only work for case classes whose members are either `Typeable` or other case classes whose members are either `Typeable` or other case classes… (and so on).

## Gotcha

Careful not to have `scala.reflect.runtime.universe._` in your imports, as this will break the above.

Comment: Changing the example as follows it does not seem to work. Any idea?

 `case class Address(street: String, zip: Int, state: String)`


    `val mp = Map(
      "name" -> "Tom",
      "address" -> Map("street" -> "Jefferson st", "zip" -> 10000, "state" ->     "CA")
    )`

Comment: @lambdista It's was a divergence issue—I've just edited the answer to be more robust.

Comment: @TravisBrown How can this be adapted to allow for some of the values in the Map to be "null". For instance `"zip" -> null`.

Comment: Got it working. Mapped over `v <- m.get(witness.value.name)` and if it returns a Some(null), pass None on. Also changed the Map to `Map[String, Option[Any]]`. Case Class types also wrapped in Options.

Comment: I'm using latest version of shapeless (2.3.3) and this doesn't compile `v <- m.get(witness.value.name)`.

Comment: @samthebest I just did a quick run with 2.3.3 and that part compiles just fine for me. You should probably open a new question with details about your Scala version, etc.

Comment: @TravisBrown Thanks, ok https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988267/why-does-this-shapeless-code-not-compile

Comment: @TravisBrown it doesn't seem to work when we have a nested structure, where the substructure is nested in an Option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042252/shapeless-code-to-convert-mapstring-any-to-case-class-cannot-handle-optional please can you help?