# Adding Container types like Seq, List, Option, and Map to shapeless generic conversion

Tags: scala, shapeless

In order to complete the series of questions that I've asked about conversion of `case class` to/from `Map[String, Any]` in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633563/converting-nested-case-classes-to-nested-maps-using-shapeless) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640565/converting-mapstring-any-to-a-case-class-using-shapeless), I wanted to know how can one extend those answers mentioned above to work with container types, specially:

- `Option`
- `Seq`
- `Set`
- `Map`
- `Tuple`s

In both case of case class `from` and `to` `Map[String, Any]`

Comment: And what would be the desired behavior of these be? `List(Foo(bar = 1, baz = "1"), Foo(bar = 2, baz = "2"))` - what would be the desired `Map[String, Any]`? Same for other collections. And what about tuples? Should you accept `"_1"`, `"_2"` as the keys?