# Unable to convert Scrooge generated classes to maps using Shapeless

Tags: scala, thrift, shapeless, scrooge

I'm using [Scrooge](https://github.com/twitter/scrooge) to generate classes. They look something like this, here's an example:

```
object Flags extends ThriftStructCodec3[Flags] {
  private val NoPassthroughFields = immutable$Map.empty[Short, TFieldBlob]
  val Struct = new TStruct("Flags")
  val IsDangerousField = new TField("isDangerous", TType.BOOL, 1)
  val IsDangerousFieldManifest = implicitly[Manifest[Boolean]]
  val IsWildField = new TField("isWild", TType.BOOL, 2)
  val IsWildFieldManifest = implicitly[Manifest[Boolean]]

  def apply(
    isDangerous: Option[Boolean] = None,
    isWild: Option[Boolean] = None
  ): Flags =
    new Immutable(
      isDangerous,
      isWild
    )

  def unapply(_item: Flags): Option[scala.Product2[Option[Boolean], Option[Boolean]]] = Some(_item)

  object Immutable extends ThriftStructCodec3[Flags] {
    override def encode(_item: Flags, _oproto: TProtocol) { _item.write(_oproto) }
    override def decode(_iprot: TProtocol): Flags = Flags.decode(_iprot)
  }

  /**
   * The default read-only implementation of Flags.  You typically should not need to
   * directly reference this class; instead, use the Flags.apply method to construct
   * new instances.
   */
  class Immutable(
    val isDangerous: Option[Boolean],
    val isWild: Option[Boolean],
    override val _passthroughFields: immutable$Map[Short, TFieldBlob]
  ) extends Flags {
    def this(
      isDangerous: Option[Boolean] = None,
      isWild: Option[Boolean] = None
    ) = this(
      isDangerous,
      isWild,
      Map.empty
    )
  }
}

trait Flags
  extends ThriftStruct
  with scala.Product2[Option[Boolean], Option[Boolean]]
  with java.io.Serializable
{
  import Flags._

  def isDangerous: Option[Boolean]
  def isWild: Option[Boolean]

  def _passthroughFields: immutable$Map[Short, TFieldBlob] = immutable$Map.empty

  def _1 = isDangerous
  def _2 = isWild

  override def productArity: Int = 2

  override def productElement(n: Int): Any = n match {
    case 0 => this.isDangerous
    case 1 => this.isWild
    case _ => throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(n.toString)
  }

  override def productPrefix: String = "Flags"
}
```

The aim is to generate from these classes a nested map using Shapeless, do some operation on it and then convert the map back to thrift generated classes.

Using [Converting nested case classes to nested Maps using Shapeless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633563/converting-nested-case-classes-to-nested-maps-using-shapeless) and [Converting Map[String,Any] to a case class using Shapeless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640565/converting-mapstring-any-to-a-case-class-using-shapeless) I managed to put together a [project](https://github.com/marialivia16/scrooge-shapeless-maps) which works fine with basic case classes. On top of the examples provided in the stack overflow responses I have also implemented implicits for Option[A].

Now, because Scrooge is not generating proper case classes I was trying to use the Immutable class instead (e.g. `Flags.Immutable`). Doing this means I have to define implicits for all the thrift classes to convert them to `NameOfClass.Immutable`. So far so good.

But I have 2 things I seem to not get right (the full implementation can be found in the `ClassToMap.scala` file):

(1) When generating the map from thrift classes the Option implicit seems to be ignored.

```
implicit def hconsToMapRecOption[K <: Symbol, V, R <: HList, T <: HList]
    (implicit
     wit: Witness.Aux[K],
     gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[V, R],
     tmrT: Lazy[ToMapRec[T]],
     tmrH: Lazy[ToMapRec[R]]
    ): ToMapRec[FieldType[K, Option[V]] :: T] = new ToMapRec[FieldType[K, Option[V]] :: T] {
      override def apply(l: FieldType[K, Option[V]] :: T): Map[String, Any] = {
        tmrT.value(l.tail) + (wit.value.name -> l.head.map(value => tmrH.value(gen.to(value))))
      }
    }
```

(2) When dealing with thrift unions my implicit is not being used.

```
implicit def hconsToMapRecGoatData[K <: Symbol, R <: HList, T <: HList]
    (implicit
     wit: Witness.Aux[K],
     gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[MyGoat, R],
     tmrT: Lazy[ToMapRec[T]],
     tmrH: Lazy[ToMapRec[R]]
    ): ToMapRec[FieldType[K, MyGoatData] :: T] = new ToMapRec[FieldType[K, MyGoatData] :: T] {
      override def apply(l: FieldType[K, MyGoatData] :: T): Map[String, Any] = {
        tmrT.value(l.tail) + (wit.value.name -> tmrH.value(gen.to(l.head.goat)))
      }
    }
```

I haven't spent so much time looking at the map to class implementation, but I assume it should mirror the class to map one.

Comment: I can't take a closer look at the moment, but are you actually getting the `LabelledGeneric` instances for the Scrooge-generated types?

Comment: Looking at the `hconsToMapRecOption` now I realise I need to somehow define the `LabelledGeneric` for Scrooge generated types. That's why it works for case classes. Am I right in thinking this is the issue? But I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I think it most likely is the issue. See [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/issues/371#issuecomment-158331777).

Comment: I've got a [small example project](https://github.com/travisbrown/scrooge-circe-demo) with some of the necessary machinery, but it's not up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you, both, this has been really helpful. I now added the required implicits and it works fine. The only thing left is adding support for unions. I'll give it a try later, although at the moment I'm not sure how this will work.