# How to convert generic potentially nested map Map[String, Any] to case class using any library in Scala?

Tags: scala, reflection, generic-programming, shapeless

I've not had much joy with reflection, this answer using shapeless works for some cases (but seems to have many edge cases) [Shapeless code to convert Map[String, Any] to case class cannot handle optional substructures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042252/shapeless-code-to-convert-mapstring-any-to-case-class-cannot-handle-optional)

Does anyone know of a nice library that does this in just a few LOCs?

Comment: Well, it can be, like to think it could come from anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use circe

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.syntax._


def mapToJson(map: Map[String, Any]): Json =
    map.mapValues(anyToJson).asJson

  def anyToJson(any: Any): Json = any match {
    case n: Int => n.asJson
    case n: Long => n.asJson
    case n: Double => n.asJson
    case s: String => s.asJson
    case true => true.asJson
    case false => false.asJson
    case null | None => None.asJson
    case list: List[_] => list.map(anyToJson).asJson
    case list: Vector[_] => list.map(anyToJson).asJson
    case Some(any) => anyToJson(any)
    case map: Map[String, Any] => mapToJson(map)
  }

def mapToCaseClass[T : Decoder](map: Map[String, Any]): T = mapToJson(map).as[T].right.get
```

Then, if we have any types that are not primitive, we just need to add these to our `anyToJson` along with an encoder/decoder pair that can encode/decode this type as something primitive.

E.g. we can represent `java.sql.Timestamp` with `Long`, then

```
import cats.syntax.either._

  import io.circe.Decoder
  import io.circe.Encoder

  implicit val decodeTimestamp: Decoder[Timestamp] = Decoder.decodeLong.emap(long =>
    Either.catchNonFatal(new Timestamp(long)).leftMap(_ => "Timestamp")
  )

implicit val encodeTimestamp: Encoder[Timestamp] = Encoder.encodeLong.contramap[Timestamp](_.getTime)
```

and we need to add the line to `anyToJson`

```
case n: Timestamp => n.asJson
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a reasonably neat way to do it using Spray Json

First we define a way to get to a `JsObject` from a `Map[String, Any]`

```
def mapToJsObject(map: Map[String, Any]): JsObject =
  JsObject(fields = map.mapValues(anyToJsValue))

def anyToJsValue(any: Any): JsValue = any match {
  case n: Int => JsNumber(n)
  case n: Long => JsNumber(n)
  case n: Double => JsNumber(n)
  case s: String => JsString(s)
  case true => JsTrue
  case false => JsFalse
  case null | None => JsNull
  case list: List[_] => JsArray(list.map(anyToJsValue).toVector)
  case Some(any) => anyToJsValue(any)
  case map: Map[String, Any] => mapToJsObject(map)
}
```

Then we can just use `convertTo` provided we have the implicit `JsonFormat` in scope

```
case class Address(street: String, zip: Int)
case class Person(name: String, address: Address)

implicit val addressFormat = jsonFormat2(Address.apply)
implicit val personFormat = jsonFormat2(Person.apply)

"Convert Person example map to Person JsObject" in {
  JsonUtils.mapToJsObject(
    Map(
      "name" -> "Tom",
      "address" -> Map("street" -> "Jefferson st", "zip" -> 10000)
    )
  ).convertTo[Person] must_=== Person("Tom", Address("Jefferson st", 10000))
}
```

## CAVEATs

Spray json only has out of box jsonFormat up to 22 fields!

Can not handle any custom types, e.g. `java.sql.Timestamp`, since this isn't a JSON type.

Answer (score 1):

Using jackson:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.8"
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.9.8"
```

```
case class Foo(a: List[Int], b: Option[Double])
case class Bar(c: Int, d: String, e: Foo)

val mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
println(mapper.convertValue(Map(
  "c" -> 3, 
  "d" -> "foo", 
  "e" -> Map("a" -> List(1, 2))), classOf[Bar]))
```

Output: `Bar(3,foo,Foo(List(1, 2),None))`