# How to serialize/deserialize case class to js.Dynamic with uPickle

Tags: scala, scala.js, upickle

I am using uPickle/ScalaJS to deserialize a js.Dynamic object into a case class using this code fragment:

```
read[myClass](JSON.stringify(dynObj))
```

where myClass is the case class and dynObj is the js.Dynamic object.

Is there a boilerplate-free and simpler way to do this?

In order to serialize a case class, I have been able to serialize to js.Dynamic using Shapeless using this example as a starting point:

[Converting nested case classes to nested Maps using Shapeless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633563/converting-nested-case-classes-to-nested-maps-using-shapeless?lq=1)

I would like to be able to use uPickle to do this instead. How can I accomplish the round-trip with uPickle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
upickle.default.readJs[myClass](upickle.json.readJs(dynObj))
```

Should do it. You can wrap it in a nice helper if you find yourself doing it a lot.

Similar calls exist to write things to `js.Dynamic`, just the other way round

```
 upickle.json.writeJs(upickle.default.writeJs[myClass](myClassInstance))
```

Though you can probably leave out the type parameter here since it'll be inferred

Answer (score 1):

The answer above no longer applies for newer versions of `upickle`.  In version `0.6.5` I had to use the following to deserialize a dynamic object:

```
val someJsObject: js.Dynamic = ...
upickle.WebJson.transform(someJsObject, implicitly[upickle.default.Reader[TargetType]])
```

To serialize, you will probably want something like:

```
val sourceObject: SourceType = ...
implicitly[upickle.default.Writer[SourceType]].write(upickle.WebJson.Builder, sourceObject)
```