# Shapeless: recursive calls in typeclass

Tags: scala, shapeless

What is the right way to implement recursive calls inside a shapeless typeclass method?

(An early caveat: I'm learning shapeless, so there may be obvious answers/alternatives I do not yet know. Any help is greatly appreciated!)

I have a typeclass which converts a case class into a nested structure of other objects—similar to and inspired by the `ToMapRec` example mentioned in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633563/converting-nested-case-classes-to-nested-maps-using-shapeless)—except that instead of returning a potentially-recursive Map, it returns a case class composed of potentially recursive members. So instead of converting an instance of `MyType`:

```
trait GetsConverted
case class MyType(someData: String, one: GetsConverted, other: GetsConverted) extends GetsConverted
case class MyOtherType(blah: AndSoOn) extends GetsConverted
case class AndSoOn(eventualFinalValue: Int)
```

into a possibly recursive/nested `Map[String,Any]`(as in the other question), it returns something like an instance of:

```
case class ReturnType(name: String, data: Option[Any], more: Set[ReturnType])
```

To create the `more` member seems to require making a recursive call inside the type class. But calling the conversion method of the type class inside of another method requires threading in the implicit parameters for all types inside that function to the outermost call. So instead of a typeclass conversion like:

```
implicit def hconsToMapRec0[K, V, A <: HList, B <: HList](implicit
  wit: Witness.Aux[K],
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[V, R],
  tmrH: Lazy[ToMapRec[A]],
  tmrT: Lazy[ToMapRec[B]]
): ReturnType = ???
```

a depth three method (I'm guessing) would require a function signature something like:

```
implicit def hconsToMapRec0[K, V, A <: HList, B <: HList, W, C <: HList, D <: HList, X, E <: HList, F <: HList](implicit
  wit: Witness.Aux[K],
  gen0: LabelledGeneric.Aux[V, A],
  tmrH0: Lazy[ToMapRec[A]],
  tmrT0: Lazy[ToMapRec[B]],
  gen1: LabelledGeneric.Aux[W, C],
  tmrH1: Lazy[ToMapRec[C]],
  tmrT1: Lazy[ToMapRec[D]],
  gen2: LabelledGeneric.Aux[X, E],
  tmrH2: Lazy[ToMapRec[E]],
  tmrT2: Lazy[ToMapRec[F]]
): ReturnType = ???
```

Or possibly worse. In general, this approach would require a method which has its implicit parameters multiplied by as many levels of depth in this recursion. And the number of levels of depth is only known at runtime. So this can't be the way to do that.

This feels analogous to the hard-coded 22-arity methods in the scala collections library. Since the raison d'être for Shapeless is to abstract over arity, this seems like a problem calling for more Shapeless-foo that I've learned so far.

So the question is: how would you write a shapeless typeclass to convert an arbitrary case class structured something like the `MyType` example above into a recursively defined value like:

```
ReturnType("MyType", Some("someData"), Set(
  ReturnType("MyOtherType", None, Set(
    ReturnType("AndSoOn", Some(10), Set())
  )), 
  ReturnType("MyOtherType", None, Set(
    ReturnType("AndSoOn", Some(20), Set())
  ))
))
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get something close to your example with the implementation below.
Most of it is similar to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633563/converting-nested-case-classes-to-nested-maps-using-shapeless) question. The difference is that it converts to the `ReturnType` and I also added a few cases for the `Coproduct` case (which is the generic representation of a `sealed trait`).

So with the following code:

```
val gen = LabelledGeneric[GetsConverted]
val m = MyType("someData", MyOtherType(AndSoOn(10)), MyOtherType(AndSoOn(20)))
val tmr = ToReturnTypeRec[gen.Repr]
val returnType = tmpr(gen.to(m))
```

You get the result

```
ReturnType(MyType,Some(someData),Set(
     ReturnType(MyOtherType,None,Set(
         ReturnType(,Some(20),Set())
     )),
     ReturnType(MyOtherType,None,Set(
         ReturnType(,Some(10),Set())
     ))
))
```

Here is the implementation:

```
trait ToReturnTypeRec[L] { def apply(l: L): ReturnType }

trait LowPriorityToReturnTypeRec {
implicit def hconsToReturnTypeRec1[K <: Symbol, V, T <: HList](implicit
    wit: Witness.Aux[K],
    tmrT: ToReturnTypeRec[T]
  ): ToReturnTypeRec[FieldType[K, V] :: T] = new ToReturnTypeRec[FieldType[K, V] :: T] {
    def apply(l: FieldType[K, V] :: T): ReturnType =
      tmrT(l.tail) match {
        case ReturnType(n,d,m) => ReturnType("", Some(l.head), m)
      }
  }
}

object ToReturnTypeRec extends LowPriorityToReturnTypeRec {
  def apply[T](implicit tmr: ToReturnTypeRec[T]) = tmr
  implicit val hnilToReturnTypeRec: ToReturnTypeRec[HNil] = new ToReturnTypeRec[HNil] {
    def apply(l: HNil): ReturnType = ReturnType("", None, Set())
  }

  implicit def hconsToReturnTypeRec0[K <: Symbol, V, T <: HList, R](implicit
    // wit: Witness.Aux[K],
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[V, R],
    tmrH: Lazy[ToReturnTypeRec[R]],
    tmrT: ToReturnTypeRec[T]
  ): ToReturnTypeRec[FieldType[K, V] :: T] = new ToReturnTypeRec[FieldType[K, V] :: T] {
    def apply(l: FieldType[K, V] :: T): ReturnType =
      tmrT(l.tail) match {
        case ReturnType(n,d,m) => ReturnType(n, d, m + tmrH.value(gen.to(l.head)))
      }
  }

  implicit val cnillToReturnTypeRec: ToReturnTypeRec[CNil] = new ToReturnTypeRec[CNil] {
    def apply(c: CNil): ReturnType = ReturnType("Impossible", None, Set())
  }

  implicit def cconsToReturnTypeRec0[K <: Symbol, V <: Product, T <: Coproduct](implicit
    wit: Witness.Aux[K],
    tmrH: Lazy[ToReturnTypeRec[V]],
    tmrT: Lazy[ToReturnTypeRec[T]]
  ): ToReturnTypeRec[FieldType[K,V] :+: T] = new ToReturnTypeRec[FieldType[K, V] :+: T] {
    def apply(c: FieldType[K,V] :+: T): ReturnType = {
      c match {
        case Inl(h) => tmrH.value(h) match {
          case ReturnType(_,d,m) => ReturnType(wit.value.name, d, m)
        }
        case Inr(t) => tmrT.value(t)
      }
    }
  }

  implicit def genericToReturnTypeRec[P, R]( implicit
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, R],
    tmr: Lazy[ToReturnTypeRec[R]]
  ): ToReturnTypeRec[P] = new ToReturnTypeRec[P] {
    def apply(p: P): ReturnType = tmr.value(gen.to(p))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! +1 for the effort, but I probably didn't do a good job of highlighting where the recursion is needed in the original querstion. This is pretty well defined in the same issue that we both linked to. But the problem comes when the call-site is inside another (recursive) function. Doing this once is straightforward, but how would you recursively call: `val returnType = tmpr(gen.to(m))`?