# scala cast object based on reflection symbol

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I have a Scala reflection Symbol.

`val symbol = scala.reflect.api.Symbol`

how can I cast an object

`val obj: Any`

to the type of that Symbol ?

reason why I am asking is that I have a implicit method to convert `Map[String, Any]` to a Scala case class, but in side I want to to cast on each field.

TODO part is the place I want to cast the type.

```
object MapStringAnyOps {
  implicit class MapStringAnyOps(m: Map[String, _]) {
    def toCaseClass[T: TypeTag : ClassTag]: T = {
      val rm = runtimeMirror(classTag[T].runtimeClass.getClassLoader)
      val destType = typeOf[T]
      val classTest = destType.typeSymbol.asClass
      val classMirror = rm.reflectClass(classTest)
      val constructor = destType.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
      val constructorMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructor)

      val constructorArgs = constructor.paramLists.flatten.map((param: Symbol) => {
        val paramName = param.name.toString
        if (param.typeSignature <:< typeOf[Option[Any]])
          m.get(paramName)  **// TODO in here, I can to cast this value of Any into the proper type of this field, but I only have Symbol so I can't simply use asInstanceOf[T]**
        else
          m.getOrElse(paramName, throw new IllegalArgumentException("Map is missing required parameter named " + paramName))
      })
      try {
        constructorMirror(constructorArgs: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
      } catch {
        case e: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException =>
          throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(s"Error mapping to class constructor:\n Casting from row: ${constructorArgs.map(r => r.getClass.getName).mkString(",")}, to constructor: ${constructor.paramLists.flatten.map(r => r.typeSignature.toString).mkString(",")}", e)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast.

In order to cast `.asInstanceOf[T]` you need to know `T` at compile time.
But you know the symbol at runtime.
You can do something later (e.g. at runtime) based on the information you get earlier (e.g. at compile time) if you persist somehow the information. But you can't cast earlier (i.e. at compile time) based on the information you get later (i.e. at runtime).

But actually you don't need to cast. `constructorMirror` accepts `Any*`.

---

Just in case, you could cast if you knew the type at compile time, e.g. if you used compile-time reflection (i.e. macros) rather than runtime reflection

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

trait ToCaseClass[T] {
  def apply(m: Map[String, _]): T
}
object ToCaseClass {
  def apply[T: ToCaseClass]: ToCaseClass[T] = implicitly

  implicit def mkToCaseClass[T]: ToCaseClass[T] = macro mkToCaseClassImpl[T]

  def mkToCaseClassImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val T = weakTypeOf[T]
    val constructor = T.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
    val constructorArgs = constructor.paramLists.flatten.map((param: Symbol) => {
      val paramName = param.name.toString
      val paramType = param.typeSignature
      q"m($paramName).asInstanceOf[$paramType]"
    })
    q"""
      new ToCaseClass[$T] {
        override def apply(m: Map[String, _]): $T = new $T(..$constructorArgs)
      }
    """
  }
}

object MapStringAnyOps {
  implicit class MapStringAnyOps(m: Map[String, _]) {
    def toCaseClass[T: ToCaseClass]: T = ToCaseClass[T].apply(m)
  }
}
```

```
case class A(i: Int, s: String)

import MapStringAnyOps._
Map("s" -> "a", "i" -> 1).toCaseClass[A] // A(1,a)
```

---

By the way, you can convert a `Map` to a case class and back using libraries

```
import shapeless.{HList, LabelledGeneric}
import shapeless.ops.maps.FromMap
import shapeless.ops.product.ToMap

def fromMap[T]: PartiallyApplied[T] = new PartiallyApplied[T]

class PartiallyApplied[T] {
  def apply[R <: HList](m: Map[Symbol, _])(implicit
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, R],
    fromMap: FromMap[R]
  ): Option[T] = fromMap(m).map(gen.from)
}

fromMap[A].apply(Map("s" -> "a", "i" -> 1)
  .map { case (k, v) => Symbol(k) -> v }) // converting Map[String, _] into Map[Symbol, _]
  .get
// A(1,a)

ToMap[A].apply(A(1, "a"))
  .map { case (k, v) => k.name -> v } // converting Map[Symbol, _] into Map[String, _]
// Map(s -> a, i -> 1)
```

In Shapeless there is a type class `ToMap` converting a case class to a `Map` but the type class `FromMap` converts a `Map` into `HList` rather than case class, that's why we need `fromMap` method.

[How to use shapeless to convert generic Map[String, Any] to case class inside generic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54988267/how-to-use-shapeless-to-convert-generic-mapstring-any-to-case-class-inside-ge)

[Shapeless code to convert Map[String, Any] to case class cannot handle optional substructures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042252/shapeless-code-to-convert-mapstring-any-to-case-class-cannot-handle-optional)

[Converting Map[String,Any] to a case class using Shapeless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640565/converting-mapstring-any-to-a-case-class-using-shapeless)

[How to convert generic potentially nested map Map[String, Any] to case class using any library in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55049985/how-to-convert-generic-potentially-nested-map-mapstring-any-to-case-class-usi)

[Scala macros for nested case classes to Map and other way around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528379/scala-macros-for-nested-case-classes-to-map-and-other-way-around)

[Converting nested case classes to nested Maps using Shapeless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633563/converting-nested-case-classes-to-nested-maps-using-shapeless)

[Convert Nested Case Classes to Nested Maps in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324512/convert-nested-case-classes-to-nested-maps-in-scala)

[Case class to map in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226555/case-class-to-map-in-scala)

[Scala: convert map to case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684572/scala-convert-map-to-case-class)

Comment: yes you are right, I know asInstanceOf won't work, but just out of curiosity, is there any way of casting type based on runtime symbol ? just like what asInstanceOf can do during compile time.

Comment: on the JVM, `asInstanceOf` has both a compile-time component and a runtime component. at compile-time, it casts to the precise type provided; at runtime, it casts to the erased type. (and as Dmytro indicates, if `T` is abstract then it erases to `Object` anyway.)

Comment: regardless, it isn't clear that your question is actually a coherent one