# Scala Macros: Checking for a certain annotation

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-macros

Thanks to the answers to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17223213/397695), I was able to create a function macro such that it returns a `Map` that maps each field name to its value of a class, e.g.

```
...

trait Model

case class User (name: String, age: Int, posts: List[String]) extends Model {
  val numPosts: Int = posts.length

  ...

  def foo = "bar"

  ...
}
```

So this command

```
val myUser = User("Foo", 25, List("Lorem", "Ipsum"))

myUser.asMap
```

returns

```
Map("name" -> "Foo", "age" -> 25, "posts" -> List("Lorem", "Ipsum"), "numPosts" -> 2)
```

This is where `Tuple`s for the `Map` are generated (see Travis Brown's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17224392/397695)):

```
...

val pairs = weakTypeOf[T].declarations.collect {
  case m: MethodSymbol if m.isAccessor =>
    val name = c.literal(m.name.decoded)
    val value = c.Expr(Select(model, m.name))
    reify(name.splice -> value.splice).tree
}

...
```

Now I want to ignore fields that have `@transient` annotation. How would I check if a method has a `@transient` annotation?

I'm thinking of modifying the snippet above as

```
val pairs = weakTypeOf[T].declarations.collect {
   case m: MethodSymbol if m.isAccessor && !m.annotations.exists(???) =>
      val name = c.literal(m.name.decoded)
      val value = c.Expr(Select(model, m.name))
      reify(name.splice -> value.splice).tree
}
```

but I can't find what I need to write in `exists` part. How would I get `@transient` as an `Annotation` so I could pass it there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The annotation will be on the `val` itself, not on the accessor. The easiest way to access the `val` is through the `accessed` method on `MethodSymbol`:

```
def isTransient(m: MethodSymbol) = m.accessed.annotations.exists(
  _.tpe =:= typeOf[scala.transient]
)
```

Now you can just write the following in your `collect`:

```
case m: MethodSymbol if m.isAccessor && !isTransient(m) =>
```

Note that the version of `isTransient` I've given here has to be defined in your macro, since it needs the imports from `c.universe`, but you could factor it out by adding a `Universe` argument if you're doing this kind of thing in several macros.

Comment: Thanks again! I can't seem to obtain annotations. I added `@transient` before `name` and `numPosts` in the example class above, but they are still added to the map. Strangely none of the methods that went through `isTransient` seems to have any annotations available. Both `m.accessed.annotations` and `m.annotations` are empty.

Comment: That's very odd—it works for me as expected in both cases. Can you maybe post your exact code?

Comment: Here's the [code](http://pastebin.com/PmW5qg3P). Note that I am building something slightly different here - a map of all fields and field types of case classes under a given package. Is the problem not having a WeakTypeTag? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Started working by itself today... I don't know what happened. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako, exactly. That's exact problem. I just found out that calling `println(m + ", " + m.typeSignature + " -> " + m.accessed.annotations.foreach(a => println(a.tpe)))` makes the macro work whereas `println(m +  " -> " + m.accessed.annotations.foreach(a => println(a.tpe)))` doesn't display anything. Came here to report it. What a coincidence, I used the exact methods to find out what was wrong. Thanks very much. That was a nasty one! :)

Comment: @TravisBrown can you also get values from the StaticAnnotation? See my question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908671/scala-macros-how-to-read-an-annotations-parameter