# scala macros: how to read an annotation object

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-macros

I want to do a similar thing as [Scala Macros: Checking for a certain annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236066/scala-macros-checking-for-a-certain-annotation)
My annotation looks like:

```
class extract(val name: String) extends StaticAnnotation
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
case class MainClass(@extract("strings") foo: String, bar: Int)
```

I'm trying to get foo parameter `Symbol` because it has an `@extract` annotation:

```
val extrList = params.map { param: Symbol =>
  param.annotations.collect {
    case extr if extr.tpe  <:< c.weakTypeOf[extract] =>
      val args = extr.scalaArgs
      if (args.size != 1)
        abort("@extract() should have exactly 1 parameter")
      getExtractValue(args.head) -> param
  }
}
```

The `getExtractValue` method looks like this:

```
def getExtractValue(tree: Tree): String = ???
```

How do I get the value `name` of the `@extract` annotation

**Update**

The Tree I get from scalaArgs seems too be unusable by c.eval()

```
param: Symbol =>
    param.annotations.collect {
      case ann if ann.tpe <:< c.weakTypeOf[extract] =>
        val args = ann.scalaArgs
        val arg0 = args.head
        val name: String = c.eval(c.Expr(arg0))
        echo(s"args @extract(name = $name)")
        name -> param
    }
```

Gives the error

```
[error] exception during macro expansion:
[error] scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective toolbox has failed: cannot
operate on trees that are already typed
[error]         at scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl$ToolBoxGlobal.
verify(ToolBoxFactory.scala:74)
```

the full stacktrace points to `c.eval` (I separated c.eval and c.Expr)

Comment: I'd rather not fall back to java annotations, since I'll have to write `@extract(name="strings")` which is longer and doesn't look that nice.

Comment: I've also asked the question, but a little different here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-language/gMlJFJz03V8/discussion

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936509/scala-macros-what-is-the-difference-between-typed-aka-typechecked-an-untyped

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case:

```
def getExtractValue(tree: Tree) = tree match {
  case Literal(Constant(str: String)) => str
}
```

Comment: What if you use a reference to a val member in an object? Would this match still work?

Comment: @Jaap No, it won't. You could still try to use `c.eval` though.

Comment: c.eval doesn't work, I'm going to try the match approach now, I wonder why I can't get a reference to the annotation object itself...

Comment: I've published the code with c.eval here: https://github.com/q42jaap/scala-extractor-annotation/tree/scala-c-eval

Comment: as Eugene Burmako posted on the scala-languague mailing list, matching on the Tree would be the best solution. I've chosen a different path which doesn't need parameters in the annotation anymore.

Comment: @Jaap link is broken.

Comment: @HassanSyed I see it is, I've apparently deleted that old branch. Since I've been doing some more macro work, I've never needed c.eval anymore. Matching string literals is realy easy with quasiquotes: `val q"${str: String}" = tree`

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/q42jaap/scala-extractor-annotation/commit/35486555d2560d61b656d68b6c8f8bef36942b48