# Detecting a macro annotated type within the body of a macro annotation

Tags: scala, macros

I want to use macro annotations (macro-paradise, Scala 2.11) to generate synthetic traits within an annotated trait's companion object. For example, given some STM abstraction:

```
trait Var[Tx, A] {
  def apply()         (implicit tx: Tx): A
  def update(value: A)(implicit tx: Tx): Unit
}
```

I want to define a macro annotation `txn` such that:

```
@txn trait Cell[A] {
  val value: A
  var next: Option[Cell[A]]
}
```

Will be re-synthesised into:

```
object Cell {
  trait Txn[-Tx, A] {
    def value: A
    def next: Var[Option[Cell.Txn[Tx, A]]] // !
  }
}
trait Cell[A] {
  val value: A
  var next: Option[Cell[A]]
}
```

I got as far as producing the companion object, the inner trait, and the `value` member. But obviously, in order for the `next` member to have the augmented type (instead of `Option[Cell[A]]`, I need `Option[Cell.Txn[Tx, A]]`), I need to pattern match the type tree and rewrite it.

For example, say I find the `next` value definition in the original `Cell` trait like this:

```
case v @ ValDef(vMods, vName, tpt, rhs) =>
```

How can I analyse `tpt` recursively to rewrite *any* type `X[...]` being annotated with `@txn` to `X.Txn[Tx, ...]`? Is this even possible, given like in the above example that `X` is yet to be processed? Should I modify `Cell` to mix-in a marker trait to be detected?

---

So the pattern matching function could start like this:

```
val tpt1 = tpt match {
  case tq"$ident" => $ident  // obviously don't change this?
  case ??? => ???
}
```

Comment: Is that STM open-source?

Comment: It is [this project](https://github.com/Sciss/LucreSTM) which wraps around [scala-stm](https://github.com/nbronson/scala-stm), possibly hooked up with a persistent store. Since writing this stuff is rather verbose, I am evaluating the possibilities to do something like the above transformation in another iteration of the library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would like to preface my answer with the disclaimer that this kind of stuff is not easy to do in current Scala. In an ideal macro system, we would like to typecheck `tpt` in its lexical context, then walk through the structure of the resulting type replacing `X[A]` with `X.Txn[Tx, A]` for those `X` that are subtypes of `TxnMarker`, and then use the resulting type in the macro expansion.

However, this kind of happy mixing of untyped trees (that come into macro annotations) and typed trees (that typechecker emits) is incompatible with how compiler internals work (some details about that can be found in [Scala macros: What is the difference between typed (aka typechecked) an untyped Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936509/scala-macros-what-is-the-difference-between-typed-aka-typechecked-an-untyped/20937159#20937159)), so we'll have to approximate.

This will be an approximation, because both in 2.10 and 2.11 our macros are unhygienic, meaning that they are vulnerable to name clashes (e.g. in the final expansion tree `Var` in `Var[...]` could bind to something unrelated if e.g. that trait we're rewriting contains a type member called `Var`). Unfortunately at the moment there's just one way to address this problem robustly, and it is very-very hard to carry out without deep understanding of compiler internals, so I'm not going into those details here.

```
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox._
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

trait Var[T]
trait TxnMarker

object txnMacro {
  def impl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._
    // NOTE: this pattern is only going to work with simple traits
    // for a full pattern that captures all traits, refer to Denys's quasiquote guide:
    // http://den.sh/quasiquotes.html#defns-summary
    val q"$mods trait $name[..$targs] extends ..$parents { ..$stats }" = annottees.head.tree
    def rewire(tpt: Tree): Tree = {
      object RewireTransformer extends Transformer {
        override def transform(tree: Tree): Tree = tree match {
          case AppliedTypeTree(x @ RefTree(xqual, xname), a :: Nil) =>
            val dummyType = q"type SomeUniqueName[T] = $x[T]"
            val dummyTrait = q"$mods trait $name[..$targs] extends ..$parents { ..${stats :+ dummyType} }"
            val dummyTrait1 = c.typecheck(dummyTrait)
            val q"$_ trait $_[..$_] extends ..$_ { ..${_ :+ dummyType1} }" = dummyTrait1
            def refersToSelf = dummyTrait1.symbol == dummyType1.symbol.info.typeSymbol
            def refersToSubtypeOfTxnMarker = dummyType1.symbol.info.baseClasses.contains(symbolOf[TxnMarker])
            if (refersToSelf || refersToSubtypeOfTxnMarker) transform(tq"${RefTree(xqual, xname.toTermName)}.Txn[Tx, $a]")
            else super.transform(tree)
          case _ =>
            super.transform(tree)
        }
      }
      RewireTransformer.transform(tpt)
    }
    val stats1 = stats map {
      // this is a simplification, probably you'll also want to do recursive rewiring and whatnot
      // but I'm omitting that here to focus on the question at hand
      case q"$mods val $name: $tpt = $_" => q"$mods def $name: $tpt"
      case q"$mods var $name: $tpt = $_" => q"$mods def $name: Var[${rewire(tpt)}]"
      case stat => stat
    }
    val annottee1 = q"$mods trait $name[..$targs] extends ..${parents :+ tq"TxnMarker"} { ..$stats }"
    val companion = q"""
      object ${name.toTermName} {
        trait Txn[Tx, A] { ..$stats1 }
      }
    """
    c.Expr[Any](Block(List(annottee1, companion), Literal(Constant(()))))
  }
}

class txn extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro txnMacro.impl
}
```

Actually, while I was writing this macro, I realized that it is ill-equipped to deal with cyclic dependencies of `@txn`-annotated definitions. The `info.baseClasses.contains(symbolOf[TxnMarker])` check essentially forces expansion of the class/trait referred to in `info`, so the macro is going to loop. This won't lead to a SOE or a freeze though - scalac will just produce a cyclic reference error and bail out.

At the moment I've no idea how to address this problem purely with macros. Maybe you could leave the code generation part in an annotation macro and then move the type transformation part into a fundep materializer. Oh right, it seems that it might work! Instead of generating

```
object Cell {
  trait Txn[-Tx, A] {
    def value: A
    def next: Var[Option[Cell.Txn[Tx, A]]]
  }
}
trait Cell[A] {
  val value: A
  var next: Option[Cell[A]]
}
```

You could actually generate this:

```
object Cell {
  trait Txn[-Tx, A] {
    def value: A
    def next[U](implicit ev: TxnTypeMapper[Option[Cell[A]], U]): U
  }
}
trait Cell[A] {
  val value: A
  var next: Option[Cell[A]]
}
```

And `TxnTypeMapper[T, U]` could be summoned by a [fundep materializer macro](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/implicits.html#fundep_materialization) that would do the `Type => Type` transformation using `Type.map`, and that one won't lead to cyclic reference errors, because by the time a materializer is invoked (during typer), all macro annotations will have already expanded. Unfortunately, I don't have time to elaborate at the moment, but this looks doable!!