# Scala macro: rewrite partial function into match

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I would like to rewrite `partial function` into `match` expression.

```
//macro and impl
def pfRewrite(pf: PartialFunction[Int, Int]) = macro ResponderImpl.pfRewriteImpl

def pfRewriteImpl(c: Context)(pf: c.Expr[PartialFunction[Int, Int]]) = {
  import c.universe._

  val cas = pf.tree.collect {
    case x: DefDef if x.name.decoded == "applyOrElse" =>
      x.collect {
        case cq"$x => $y" =>  cq"""$x => $y"""
      }
  }.flatten

  val sVal = newTermName("someVal")

  val rewrite = q"""
    $sVal match {
      case ..$cas
    }
  """
  c.Expr(rewrite)
}
```

In code i got a `PartialFunction` and take a `cases` from `applyOrElse` method, next i create a `match` expression for "someVal". This value from code:

```
 //test
 def test {
  val someVal = 10

  pfRewrite {
   case 1 => 10
   case _ => 100
  }
 }
```

But i got errors:

```
[error]  found   : Int(10)
[error]  required: Nothing
[error]       case 1 => 10
[error]                 ^
```

and etc.

It possible rewrite partial function call into match ?

Comment: Could you state which is the output tree you expect?

Comment: It will be used into runtime, and `someVal` as method params: `def mth(s: Int) = { pfRewrite { case 1 => 10 ; case _ => 100 } }` transform into `mth(s: Int) = { s match { ... } }`. Or what do you mean?

Comment: How would pfRewrite know that it needs to match s?

Comment: Also, have you tried calling resetLocalAttrs on rewrite?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako no, i have not used `resetLocalAttrs`. `s` is an attribute name. Now, i want to rewrite `case` blocks- `case x: Int => x` translate to `case x: Int => x + 100`. It possible or it's hard?

Comment: Still don't follow how the macro would figure out that it has to match `s`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically these kinds of awkward error messages stem from mixing typed and untyped trees (for more details take a look at [Scala macros: What is the difference between typed (aka typechecked) an untyped Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936509/scala-macros-what-is-the-difference-between-typed-aka-typechecked-an-untyped)). Therefore, until we've fixed the situation, it's good practice to do resetLocalAttrs on typed trees that you plan to mix with untyped ones.

This case is not an exception. Using `c.resetLocalAttrs(pf.tree)` instead of just `pf.tree` reveals the real problem with the macro expansion:

```
12:57 ~/Projects/Master/sandbox (master)$ scalac Test.scala
Test.scala:5: error: not found: value default
     Macros.pfRewrite {
                      ^
```

If we enable `-Xprint:typer`, which is one of the ways to see macro expansions (along with `-Ymacro-debug-lite` and `-Ymacro-debug-verbose`), then we'll see what's going on:

```
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // Test.scala
package <empty> {
  object Test extends AnyRef with App {
    def <init>(): Test.type = {
      Test.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def test: Unit = {
      val someVal: Int = 10;
      {
        someVal match {
          case 1 => 10
          case _ => 100
          case (defaultCase$ @ _) => <default: error>.apply(<x1: error>)
        };
        ()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It looks like partial function synthesis also adds a default case that we can't reuse as-is, as it refers to some synthetic variables defined in the synthesized class.