# How do I get the type from an Ident() in a macro?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm trying to write a generic macro in which I can grab any trees that match `foo.bar`, but only where `foo` is a `Foo`. I only need to look inside the enclosing class where the macro is called. So far I have this:

```
def getFooTrees[T](): Unit = macro getFooTrees_impl[T]

def getFooTrees_impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.universe._

  val receiverType = implicitly[c.WeakTypeTag[T]].tpe
  val terms = c.enclosingClass  
    .filter { t =>
      t match {
        case Select(ident: Ident, name: TermName) if (??? == receiverType) =>
          true
        case _ =>
          false
      }
    }

  ...etc

}
```

How do I check the type of what `ident` refers to? Sorry if I'm totally lost in the woods here.

Comment: Do you mean ident.tpe?

Comment: Huh - that seems right, but it's also null sometimes. I can update the code with the enclosing class I'm using to test, if that's helpful.

Comment: Also, if I `showRaw(ident.tpe)`, it looks like `SingleType(NoPrefix, newTermName("bar"))`. I'm not quite sure what to do with that

Comment: tpe is null if the tree isn't typechecked yet (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936509/scala-macros-what-is-the-difference-between-typed-aka-typechecked-an-untyped for more information).

Comment: If you elaborate on what you need the tpe for, I could help you with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Question probably long dormant but I had same problem

```
val ident: Ident = ... 
ident.tpe  // is null

val tree2 = c.typecheck(tree = ident,mode = c.TYPEmode)
tree2.tpe  // not null
```