# How to debug scalajs linker error: non-existent method java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields

Tags: scala, linker, scala.js

After adding the following method to **map case classes to `Map` or `js.Dictionary`** - and I've tried now five or six variants of the following - my code compiles fine and without warnings, but then hits errors at the `fastOptJS` `sjs` linking stage.

#### The method

```
  def ccToMap(cc: AnyRef) =
    (Map[String, Any]() /: cc.getClass.getDeclaredFields) {
      (a, f) =>
        f.setAccessible(true)
        a + (f.getName -> f.get(cc))
    }
```

*Note that all the variants I have tried do the same thing in a slightly different manner.*

#### The error

```
 [info] Fast optimizing /Users/justin/Desktop/arete/jt/client/target/scala-2.11/client-fastopt.js
 [error] Referring to non-existent class java.lang.reflect.Field
 [error]   called from com.jshin47.jtdc.client.module.visualization.DiodeStateVizC$.ccToMap(java.lang.Object)scala.collection.immutable.Map
 [error]   called from com.jshin47.jtdc.client.module.visualization.DiodeStateVizC$.<init>()
 [error]   called from com.jshin47.jtdc.client.module.landing.LandingLocC$$anonfun$2.apply(japgolly.scalajs.react.extra.router.RouterCtl)japgolly.scalajs.react.ReactElement
 [error]   called from com.jshin47.jtdc.client.module.landing.LandingLocC$$anonfun$2.apply(java.lang.Object)java.lang.Object
 [error]   called from scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized,scala.Function1)scala.Unit
 [error]   called from scala.collection.mutable.MutableList.foreach(scala.Function1)scala.Unit
 [error]   called from scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(scala.Function1,scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom)java.lang.Object
 [error]   called from scala.collection.immutable.Stream$StreamWithFilter.map(scala.Function1,scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom)java.lang.Object
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.Slave.org$scalajs$testinterface$internal$Slave$$execute(scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic)scala.Unit
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.Slave.handleMsgImpl(java.lang.String,scala.Function0)scala.Unit
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.BridgeBase.handleMsg(java.lang.String)scala.Unit
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.BridgeBase.$$anonfun$1(java.lang.String)scala.Unit
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.BridgeBase.init()scala.Unit
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.BridgeBase.$$js$exported$meth$init()java.lang.Object
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.BridgeBase.init
 [error]   exported to JavaScript with @JSExport
 [error] involving instantiated classes:
 [error]   com.jshin47.jtdc.client.module.visualization.DiodeStateVizC$
 [error]   com.jshin47.jtdc.client.module.landing.LandingLocC$$anonfun$2
 [error]   scala.collection.mutable.Queue
 [error]   scala.collection.mutable.MutableList
 [error]   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter
 [error]   scala.collection.immutable.Stream$StreamWithFilter
 [error]   org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.Slave
 [error]   org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.Master
 [error] Referring to non-existent method java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields()     [java.lang.reflect.Field
 [error]   called from com.jshin47.jtdc.client.module.visualization.DiodeStateVizC$.ccToMap(java.lang.Object)scala.collection.immutable.Map
 [error]   called from com.jshin47.jtdc.client.module.visualization.DiodeStateVizC$.<init>()
 [error]   called from com.jshin47.jtdc.client.module.landing.LandingLocC$$anonfun$2.apply(japgolly.scalajs.react.extra.router.RouterCtl)japgolly.scalajs.react.ReactElement
 [error]   called from com.jshin47.jtdc.client.module.landing.LandingLocC$$anonfun$2.apply(java.lang.Object)java.lang.Object
 [error]   called from scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized,scala.Function1)scala.Unit
 [error]   called from scala.collection.mutable.MutableList.foreach(scala.Function1)scala.Unit
 [error]   called from scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(scala.Function1,scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom)java.lang.Object
 [error]   called from scala.collection.immutable.Stream$StreamWithFilter.map(scala.Function1,scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom)java.lang.Object
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.Slave.org$scalajs$testinterface$internal$Slave$$execute(scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic)scala.Unit
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.Slave.handleMsgImpl(java.lang.String,scala.Function0)scala.Unit
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.BridgeBase.handleMsg(java.lang.String)scala.Unit
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.BridgeBase.$$anonfun$1(java.lang.String)scala.Unit
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.BridgeBase.init()scala.Unit
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.BridgeBase.$$js$exported$meth$init()java.lang.Object
 [error]   called from org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.BridgeBase.init
 [error]   exported to JavaScript with @JSExport
 [error] involving instantiated classes:
 [error]   com.jshin47.jtdc.client.module.visualization.DiodeStateVizC$
 [error]   com.jshin47.jtdc.client.module.landing.LandingLocC$$anonfun$2
 [error]   scala.collection.mutable.Queue
 [error]   scala.collection.mutable.MutableList
 [error]   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter
 [error]   scala.collection.immutable.Stream$StreamWithFilter
 [error]   org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.Slave
 [error]   org.scalajs.testinterface.internal.Master
 [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last client/compile:fastOptJS for the full output.
 [error] (client/compile:fastOptJS) There were linking errors
 [error] Total time: 36 s, completed May 10, 2016 2:01:07 AM
```

#### What I've tried

Being unfamiliar with the details of the linker I am only able to try some "obvious" diagnostics:

- Whether I call the method or not, this error is thrown (it doesn't have to be in the code path, so this is getting thrown when the method itself is linked)
- The `Map` type itself works just fine as an argument to the function where I am trying to invoke this
- I know to a **certainty** that **iff** this method (or similar) is present, then I get the above linker error. (Without, no error.)

Any tips on how to proceed, debug, etc are appreciated.

Alternatively, any tips on how I may convert a `case class` to a `Map` without the above-style (reflection-based) function, please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply can't use Java reflection in Scala.js:

> [Java reflection and, a fortiori, Scala reflection, are not supported. There is limited support for java.lang.Class, e.g., obj.getClass.getName will work for any Scala.js object (not for objects that come from JavaScript interop).](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/semantics.html)

Use macros for this instead. See e.g. [Scala Macros: Making a Map out of fields of a class in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223213/scala-macros-making-a-map-out-of-fields-of-a-class-in-scala)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the macro. That helps a lot, I was starting to write `toMap` methods everwehere

Comment: Question: how do you make the linked rescurse?