# Scala map collection case-class to Map()

Tags: scala, scala-macros, case-class, seq

I have 2 case-classes:

```
case class OutlierPortal(portal: String, timeData: Seq[OutlierPortalTimeSeriesData])
```

and

```
case class OutlierPortalTimeSeriesData(period: Timestamp, totalAmount: Double, isOutlier: Int)
```

or respectively a `Seq[OutlierPortal]`

What I want to perform is similar to [Scala Macros: Making a Map out of fields of a class in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223213/scala-macros-making-a-map-out-of-fields-of-a-class-in-scala), but I want to map a sequence of a (nested) case-classes to `Seq[Map[String, Any]]`.

However, new to scala I fear a bit the proposed idea of **macros**. Is there a "simpler" way to map this Sequence of `Seq[OutlierPortal]` to `Seq[Map[String, Any]]`

Or would you recommend to start using macros even though a beginner in scala? For me a one-way conversion (case-class -> map) is enough.

Comment: To be clear, you're looking to avoid hard-coding the strings?

Comment: Flexible keys would be nice but is not mandatory

Comment: You want the `value` of type `Any` to contain the fields value?

Comment: Also, have you seen the answers to this question? Might be a duplicate of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226555/case-class-to-map-in-scala

Comment: @danGetz is this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226555/case-class-to-map-in-scala preferable over macros? what is the advantage of macros over this short-hand solution?

Comment: @geoHeil That other method uses Java reflection. Macros generate code at compile time, so should have better performance than reflection. With either of those solutions, you only need to write them once, then you can use them with as many case classes as you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to avoid fancy tricks, and you don't have too many total classes to write this for, you can just write the methods to create the maps yourself. I'd suggest adding methods named something like `toMap` to your case classes. `OutlierPortalTimeSeriesData`'s is simple if you use the `Map()` constructor:

```
case class OutlierPortalTimeSeriesData(period: Timestamp, totalAmount: Double, isOutlier: Int) {
  def toMap: Map[String, Any] = Map(
    "period" -> period,
    "totalAmount" -> totalAmount,
    "isOutlier" -> isOutlier)
}
```

I suppose there's some duplication there, but at least if you ever have a reason to change the string values but not the variable names, you have the flexibility to do that.

To take a sequence of something you can call `toMap` on, and turn it into a `Seq[Map[String, Any]]`, just use `map`:

```
mySeq.map { _.toMap }
```

We can use this both to write `OutlierPortal`'s `toMap`:

```
case class OutlierPortal(portal: String, timeData: Seq[OutlierPortalTimeSeriesData]) {
  def toMap: Map[String, Any] = Map(
    "portal" -> portal,
    "timeData" -> timeData.map { _.toMap })
}
```

and then again to convert a `Seq[OutlierPortal]` to a `Seq[Map[String, Any]]`.

Depending on how you're using these objects and methods, you might want to define a trait that distinguishes classes with this method, and have your case classes extend it:

```
trait HasToMap { def toMap: Map[String, Any] }
case class Blah( /* ... */ ) extends HasToMap {
  def toMap: /* ... */ }
}
```

This would let you take a value that you know you can convert to `Map[String, Any]` (or a sequence of them, etc.) in a method that otherwise doesn't care which particular type it is.

Comment: Implementing this solution for now I get the following error: `def mapOutliersForJobserver(outliers: Future[Seq[OutlierPortal]]): Future[Seq[Map[String, Any]]] = {
    outliers.map( _.toMap)
  }` error: `Future[Map[Nothing, Nothing]] does not conform to type Future[Seq[Map[String, Any]]]`  What is the problem here? ist it the Seq[T]?

Comment: @geoHeil You're trying to treat a `Future[Seq[T]]` the same as a `Seq[T]`. They're different, though, just as a `Seq[Seq[T]]` would be.

Comment: @geoHeil so for example you could use two nested calls to `map` like `{outliers.map { _.map { _.toMap } }`. There must be a cleaner way to do it though.